# running pyspark script using spark REST API

Tags: python, rest, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to learn how to run a pyspark script using SPARK REST API.

I followed this link: http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api
and found this:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "pi.py" ],
"appResource" : "file:learning/pi.py",
"clientSparkVersion" : "1.6.1",
"environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
"mainClass" : "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
"spark.app.name" : "Simple App",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "spark://localhost:6066"
}
}'
```

Well it worked but I don't know what

```
"SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
```

means. Can someone explain please? it will help me proceed further.

Also, If someone knows a better way of doing the same please let me know. I am new at this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check [`load-spark-env.sh`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/bin/load-spark-env.sh).

> This script loads spark-env.sh if it exists, and ensures it is **only loaded once**.
>   spark-env.sh is loaded from SPARK_CONF_DIR if set, or within the current directory's
>   conf/ subdirectory.

here if statement checks whether `SPARK_ENV_LOADED` was initialized (expression *-z True if string is empty.*):

```
if [ -z "$SPARK_ENV_LOADED" ]; then
  export SPARK_ENV_LOADED=1

  # Returns the parent of the directory this script lives in.
  parent_dir="${SPARK_HOME}"

  user_conf_dir="${SPARK_CONF_DIR:-"$parent_dir"/conf}"

  if [ -f "${user_conf_dir}/spark-env.sh" ]; then
    # Promote all variable declarations to environment (exported) variables
    set -a
    . "${user_conf_dir}/spark-env.sh"
    set +a
  fi
fi
```